# Install package from cran, status 127, status 1

Tags: r, dplyr, package, virtual-machine, cran

**i'm working in a virtual machine R studio version 0.98.507.0 and R 3.1.1 => i can not update it.**

I wanna install packages *dplyr* but it's only avaible for R 3.1.2

that why i'm trying to install an old version of *dplyr*

when i try to download the files and install it with

```
install.packages("files://..)
```

nothings work so i have to install it directly from CRAN website. I have been able to install some packages with

```
install.packages("http://...")
```

for *dplyr* here what its return

1)

I run

```
    path<- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz"

install.packages(path, repos=NULL,type="source")
```

I have

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/I0368711/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 891010 bytes (870 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 870 Kb

* installing *source* package 'dplyr' ...
** package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="dplyr.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o address.o arrange.o between.o bind.o combine_variables.o distinct.o dplyr.o filter.o group_indices.o init.o join.o select.o strings_addresses.o summarise.o test.o window.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'dplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/I0368711/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/dplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\I0368711\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "C:/Users/I0368711/AppData/Local/Temp/61/RtmpegYHgi/downloaded_packages/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/I0368711/AppData/Local/Temp/61/RtmpegYHgi/downloaded_packages/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

It's look like R is able to download the file but something goes wrong and i dont understand a single line of the error message..

I also tryied

2)

```
install.packages(path, repos=NULL)
```

the error message is:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/I0368711/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 891010 bytes (870 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 870 Kb

Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Sorry for my bad englihs i made my best to create and understable topic

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed on the machine? Because if you haven't, you simply can't install older versions from source (and binaries are probably not available anywhere).

Comment: hello, i do not have Rtools but i'm not administrator and i can not install anything in the machine. You are agree Rtools has to be installed in the machine and it's doesnt work like a package? You are right the packages i installed from sources are actual version packages. So for you, i'm gonna have to keep trying to install it from the files downladed as long as i cant install Rtools? Thanks for your time

Comment: Rtools is not a package, it's a tool set needed to create packages from source files on Windows. If you don't have Rtools you are stuck and need to bother the administrator (preferable ask them to install more current versions of R, RStudio and Rtools).

Comment: ok thanks you a lot!